# Do electrons move faster towards the end of a circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields, electricity, electric-current, potential

As 1 coulomb electrons go through 1 volt of potential difference, they gain 1 joule of energy. So in s series circuit, do electrons move faster towards the end of the circuit where they went though a larger potential difference? If so, how is the current through a series circuit constant?

Comment: You need to clarify what the circuit is. Assuming it is built from wires, resistors, etc, you might want to look at ["Speed of electrons in a current-carrying metallic wire: does it even make sense?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/388057/145491), ["Drift velocity in Drude model"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/323959/145491), ["Why doesn’t drift velocity increase along a wire?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/696457/145491).

Answer (score 1):

If that circuit is an accelerator beam pipe, then: yes, that's the point.

If it's something with plain old resistance, then they *loose* $IV\tau = 1\,{\rm J}$ of energy to resistive heating, where tau is the unspecified time over which this 1 C drops 1 V.